# "TypeError: Image data can not convert to float" unsing matplotlib in python27

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([]) # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
plt.show()
```

when input the code as picture showing, the shell output the error as title

```
"TypeError: Image data can not convert to float"
```

i don't know how to solve the problem, i expect the answer.thank you very much

[image]

Comment: can you paste the code into the question instead of an image so we can copy and paste it to run it

Comment: ok, I will try it at once. sorry, i am the freshman in this part

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well, so I suppose the file path is not correct, try to run this to check out the file path:

```
import os
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

path='messi5.jpg'

if os.path.isfile(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path,0)
    plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([]) # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
    plt.show()
else:
    print("file not exists")
```

Comment: what you said is completely right, I tried your code and changed the path(add the complete image path), both were OK. thank you very much